# For loop and errorlevel variable

Tags: windows, batch

Having such simple batch script

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in (toFind.txt) do (

    find /c "%%f" 1.txt
    
    if errorlevel 0 (
        echo %%f "--->" found 
    )   else (
        echo %%f "--->" not found!
    )
)
```

it ALWAYS returns `... found` even if the string (from a *toFind.txt* file) IS'T exist in the *1.txt* file...

Comment: Could you clear up your last sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old IF ERRORLEVEL syntax from MS-DOS.

`IF ERRORLEVEL N do_something` means "If errorlevel is greater than or equal to N do_something"

Since ERRORLEVEL will always be greater than or equal to 0, you will always get the "found" message even when FIND returns a nonzero error.

What you want is the Windows NT modern version where errorlevel is a proper variable.

`IF %errorlevel% equ 0 do_something`

However you are in a loop so you need delayed expansion and you use ! instead of % around errorlevel

`IF !errorlevel! equ 0 do_something`

so try this

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in (toFind.txt) do (

    find /c "%%f" 1.txt
    
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
        echo %%f "--->" found 
    )   else (
        echo %%f "--->" not found!
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can use operators (**`&& == return 0`**  and **`|| == return non 0`**) instead **`errolevel`**

**2.** Use/add **`Usebackq`** in your `For /F` loop, this will output the lines one by one as if in double quotes, avoiding possible failures where the lines contain `&`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `&`, `<`, `>`, etc.

**3.** By using **`setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`**, the "**`!`**" will not be treated as a character, failing to compare lines where it contains in both files.

```bat
@echo off 

for /f usebackq^tokens^=* %%f in (toFind.txt
    ) do find/c "%%~f" <1.txt >nul && (
         echo\%%~f ---^> found!
    ) || echo\%%~f ---^> not found!
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [`For /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [`Errolevel /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)

  - [`Setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) & [`Endlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: The Additional Resources section was very useful. Much appreciated!